# Is there a quick way to know if WKWebView can load a local file at path?

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

I have a basic iOS app with the `WKWebView` that is used to open various document files stored locally. Here is my code snippet on how to load a sample .doc file in Web view, which works great.

```
guard let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sampleFile", withExtension: ".doc") else {
    fatalError("Failed to obtain file URL for: sampleFile.doc")
}

webView.loadFileURL(fileURL, allowingReadAccessTo: fileURL)
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

Now, is there a way for `WKWebView` to respond in case some file with some random extension that cannot be opened, or that the file is corrupt?

I am new to this `WebKit` API, that is why I am asking for a best solution for this? Also, is there some `WKNavigationDelegate` method that gets called in case a file is corrupt or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I believe you'd need to employ WKNavigationDelegate, which will tell you if there's an error loading a resource: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455623-webview

You can then respond to the error as appropriate. I can see you've already assigned the calling class as a navigationDelegate, so all you need to do is implement `webView(_:didFail:withError:)`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in my case, it was actually this delegate function that responded with error when cannot open unknown local file. webView(_:didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError:)

Comment: Why not respond to the error by loading a default error page in the webview, or displaying a message to the user?

Comment: My app is a document viewer. For this case, I will present a plain UIAlertView to the user with the error. But just I'm a bit confused for error message that I get when WKWebView cannot open a file. It's domain is: Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted". I'm not sure if this particular error domain is correct for opening corrupt files/files with unknown extension. This is the only thing left to handle

Comment: If you look around, there are other comments on SO suggesting that this issue only happens on the simulator, and not on real devices. I'm not sure how true that is, but several people have said the same thing. Could also be to do with the type of file you're trying to load. Maybe Webkit doesn't know how to handle this particular file type?